# Combining array of strings until they attain a certain length

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array

Duplicate of: [Combining strings in an array upto certain length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47031239/combining-strings-in-an-array-upto-certain-length)

```
var chars = 100;

var s = [
"when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book",  //contains 91 chars
"essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release",          //contains 71 chars
"unchanged essentially. popularised It was in the 1960s with the release",          //contains 71 chars
"It is a long established", //contains 24 chars
"search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years",    //contains 121 chars
"injected humour and the like"          //contains 28 chars
]
```

I want to join (by \n) the next sentence if the number of characters in the present sentence is **LESS** than the variable `chars=100`

if `chars=100` then

1) `s[0]` is less than 100 so I will have to join `s[1]` and `s[1]`

2) `s[2]` is less than 100 so I will have to join `s[3]` but still after combining they are 95 hence I need to further join `s[4]`

3) display `s[5]` as the list is empty

**Expected Output:**

1) when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
       essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release

2) unchanged essentially. popularised It was in the 1960s with the release
       It is a long established
       search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years

3) injected humour and the like

How do I implement in JS with fastest code possible?

```
var x = "";
var y = [];
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
 if(x.length<100)
 {
    x=x+s[i];
    continue;
 }
y.push(x)
x="";

}

y.push(x)
console.log(y.join("\n\n"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining strings in an array upto certain length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47031239/combining-strings-in-an-array-upto-certain-length)

Comment: Please don't clear the content of the question. Instead delete it, if you think it doesn't help any future reader.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the words by doing something like

```
return str.split(' ').length;
```

this will return the length of an array with each word as index.

But you should try your own and we can help fixing your trys!

Comment: Yes, I know. This is the first hint. This wont split your sentence, just returns the length of your sentence. Try your own and we help fixing

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood smth. I thought you want each sentence to be 100 words not 100 characters...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you have an output string and iterate over the array and append an element to the array every time that your condition is met.

Like so:

```
var outputString = "";
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if(s[i].length < 100) {
        outputString.append(s[i])
    }
}
return outputString
```

Comment: This is not the expected one. You can check the expected OUTPUT given in the question